# R Markdown: hide spoiler text (hover over text element)

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

Is it possible to hide blocks of text within .html files created with R Markdown? The elements of text should be hidden until the user hovers over the text preferentially (or clicks a button). The elements to be hidden do not concern code blocks. Currently I include text within < p> < /p>

It was suggested to hide text blocks by preceding each line with '>!', but R Studio does not recognize this 'markdown' approach. It just returns a text block that starts with '!'.  I prefer this simple 'hover' approach though, above Javascript and buttons.

Any suggestions would be welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My suggestion is to use CSS for this task.

The following `Rmd` file includes some rules to hide the `spoiler` class elements. You may find other approaches with CSS:

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{css, echo=FALSE}
.spoiler {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.spoiler::before {
  visibility: visible;
  content: "Spoiler alert! Hover me to see the answer."
}

.spoiler:hover {
  visibility: visible;
}

.spoiler:hover::before {
  display: none;
}
```

You can insert a message in raw `HTML`:
<p class="spoiler">Answer</p>

A better approach is to use bracketed spans:  
[This is another answer]{.spoiler}
````

Comment: Also worth mentioning: [fenced divs](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#fenced_divs), which can eliminate the need for raw HTML in the input.

Answer (score 7):

Based on the additional part about wanting to reveal a `kable`'d table, I took a look at some functions from the `htmltools` package for creating HTML elements. The way I came up with uses just the smallest amount of Javascript, via a `js` code block.

Basically, I create a button using `shiny::actionButton` and attach to it a Javascript click handler by supplying a function name to the `onclick` attribute. The knit table is inside a `HTML` wrapper so that it will render properly, inside a `<div>` element as a container. This container has a [`hidden` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/hidden) initially set to true.

The click handler is the only real Javascript to write, and that's a function that finds the `<div>` by ID, and sets its `hidden` property to false.

The RMarkdown:

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

```{r}
library(htmltools)

shiny::actionButton("show_table_button", 
                    label = "Show table", 
                    onclick = "button_handler()")

div(id = "tableContainer", 
    hidden = "true",
    HTML(knitr::kable(head(iris), format = "html")))
```

```{js}
function button_handler() {
  document.getElementById('tableContainer').hidden = false;
}
```
````

That creates:

[image: hidden = true]

After clicking the button:

[image: hidden = false]

Note that there are some other packages for writing more complex Javascript code in R—haven't used any to recommend one—but I tried to keep the packages limited to what you would already have from using anything Shiny / HTML Widgets related.

Comment: is there a way to add a "hide table" button to hide it back if you don't want to see it anymore?

Comment: I'd honestly try using a pre-built HTML widgets library instead of writing javascript in R, but you could instead toggle `document.getElementById('tableContainer').hidden` in the click handler

Answer (score 5):

This is of course possible. There are several possibilities including linear transformations (animated fading), buttons, no buttons and so on.

To start with, here is a simple approach using CSS. When not hovered, the font and background colors match and therefore no text is visible. When hovered the background turns white and the text turns black.

```
---
title: "Hide Code Blocks"
author: "Martin Schmelzer"
date: "June 25, 2018"
output: html_document
---

<style>
hide {
  background-color: #d6d6d6;
  color: #d6d6d6;
}
hide:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
</style>

## R Markdown

<hide>This is a hidden text block!</hide>
```